# Cutter with arm debugging

Tags: arm, radare2

I've been able to run the debugger inside Cutter (radare2) using my native host (x86_64) libraries when reversing a x86 binary. How would I do such a thing when trying to debug an arm binary? How can I get cutter to use the libc.so for arm instead of my native host so I can debug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***ENVIRONMENT***

- **Cutter:** Version 1.10.0, Using r2-4.1.1, Based on Qt 5.12.1 (GCC 7.4.0, 64 bit)
- **System:** Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

***SOLUTION***

- **Note: As of Cutter v1.10.0 debugging is still in beta, therefore these results may vary and change over time.**

[image: debug_is_beta]

- Option 1: Utilize the emulation features of Cutter instead of debugging.
- Option 2: Connect Cutter to a remote session.

***EXAMPLE***

**Option 1**

Open Cutter with target ARM binary and seek to main function.

[image: seek_to_main]

Select "Start emulation" from Debug menu.

[image: debug_menu]

Set breakpoints/step/continue as if debugging.

[image: debug_like_normal]

**Option 2**

Open Cutter with target ARM binary and seek to main function.

[image: seek_to_main]

Launch remote session for target ARM binary.

```sh
user@host:~$ qemu-arm -g 5000 test.x
```

Select "Connect to a remote debugger" from Debug menu.

[image: debug_menu]

Target the remote debugger.

[image: remote_config]

Set breakpoints/step/continue like normal.

[image: debug_like_normal]